# Node.js displaying users-email from mongo to form-select.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a node.js app that uses Mongodb and ejs. I'm trying to display users from mongo in a select but I've got a lot of errors.

This is user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    }});
```

This is the route of the form:

```
    app.get('/create', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var User            = require('../app/models/user');
    var to = null;
    User.find(function(err, users) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        to = json(users);
    });
    res.render('create.ejs', {
        users : to
    });
});
```

I'm trying to send is as a json. I can display it in json format but i don't know how parse it to template.I also tried a lot of different way.

And this is the part of html code with that select:

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" >
          <% for(var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) { %>
                   <option value="gi"><%= users[i].email %></option>
          <% } %>
</select>
```

If any one could help me. I would be very grateful !

Comment: i'm using : http://ejs.co/

Comment: Put the res.render in the callback for the user.find

Comment: it works, THANK YOU !!!